# reload option in nautilus (files) does not work

Tags: gnome, 18.04, nautilus

ubuntu 18.04, gnome shell 3.28.3, files version 3.26.4.

When I open a window in Files (Nautilus), on the top right of the window is a "hamburger" menu button.  When I click on that, a dropdown menu appears, the last item in that menu at the bottom is "Reload".  It used to be I could highlight "Reload" and click on it, and the contents of the directory I had visible in the window would refresh.  Recently I've noticed that I am now never permitted to even highlight the "Reload" item in the menu, even though it appears in the menu, and it is not greyed out.

Why is it acting like this?

How do I restore the ability to reload a directory's content with this menu item?

Comment: Can't reproduce this currently. Files is version 3.26.3, Gnome 3.28.2.